# Using excel, concatenate the first four characters in second column if present to the first four characters of data in the first column

Tags: vba, excel

I intending to maintain a list of VID and PID of USB devices in Microsoft SQL database. The list can be obtained from this site: http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids

Example format of source from the site:

```
0001  Fry's Electronics
    142b  Arbiter Systems, Inc.
    7778  Counterfeit flash drive [Kingston]
0002  Ingram
0003  Club Mac
0004  Nebraska Furniture Mart
0011  Unknown manufacturer
    7788  Flash mass storage drive
0053  Planex
    5301  GW-US54ZGL 802.11bg
0079  DragonRise Inc.
    0006  PC TWIN SHOCK Gamepad
    0011  Gamepad
0105  Trust International B.V.
    145f  NW-3100 802.11b/g 54Mbps Wireless Network Adapter [zd1211]
0145  Unknown
    0112  Card Reader
017c  MLK
    145f  Trust Deskset
0200  TP-Link
    0201  MA180 UMTS Modem
0204  Chipsbank Microelectronics Co., Ltd
    6025  CBM2080 / CBM2090 Flash drive controller
    6026  CBM1180 Flash drive controller
...
```

Example of format of the values found in table of SQL database:

```
0001142b  Fry's Electronics Arbiter Systems, Inc.
00017778  Fry's Electronics Counterfeit flash drive [Kingston]
0002  Ingram
0003  Club Mac
0004  Nebraska Furniture Mart
00117788  Unknown manufacturer Flash mass storage drive       
00535301  Planex GW-US54ZGL 802.11bg
...
```

So my intended approach to load this into the DB is to use excel VBA/Macro for the processing, whereby I would I concatenate the first four characters(PID) in the second column if present, to the first four characters(VID) in the first column.

So can I get help from the Excel experts and gurus, how can I achieve this in the simplest way manner, using VBA or a macro?

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple actually. What I did was copied the data from the above link and pasted it in a notepad as shown below. I am just taking 27 odd lines for demonstration purpose.

[image]

**Logic:**

1. Read the entire file in an array (Say `MyData`) in one go!
2. Create a new array to store the output
3. Loop through `MyData` and check if the first character is not blank. (Horz Tab actually). Hence we cannot use `Len(Trim())`
4. If it is not then it becomes our PREFIX
5. If it is then we loop through the array again and check till where do we have the records which have `Horz Tab` as the first char and this becomes or SUFFIX. Simply join them and store them in the output array, Say `MyFinalData`

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
    Dim MyFinalData() As String, sPrefix As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long

    '~~> Open text file and read into the array in one go
    Open "C:\sample.Txt" For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData

    '~~> Close Text File
    Close #1

    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

    ReDim Preserve MyFinalData(UBound(strData) + 1)

    For i = 0 To UBound(strData)
        If Asc(Left(strData(i), 1)) <> 9 Then _
        sPrefix = Split(strData(i), " ")(0)

        If Not i = UBound(strData) Then
            If Asc(Left(strData(i + 1), 1)) = 9 Then
                For j = i + 1 To UBound(strData)
                    If Asc(Left(strData(j), 1)) <> 9 Then
                        i = j - 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    MyFinalData(n) = sPrefix & _
                                     Trim(Replace(strData(j), vbTab, ""))
                    n = n + 1
                Next j
            Else
                MyFinalData(n) = strData(i)
                n = n + 1
            End If
        End If

        sPrefix = ""
    Next i

    '~~> Showing output here. You can directly write this data to an 
    '~~> excel sheet if you want.
    For i = LBound(MyFinalData) To UBound(MyFinalData)
        Debug.Print MyFinalData(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind a makeshift approach, you could try the following:

1. copy and paste the output on an excel file starting from cell A2 (not A1)
   Evertything will be pasted in column 1
2. in cel B2 enter: =IF(LEFT(A2;4)="    ";B1;LEFT(A2;4))
3. in cel C2 enter: =IF(LEFT(A2;4)="    ";MID(A2;5;4);"Father")
4. in cel D2 enter: =IF(LEFT(A2;4)="    ";D1;MID(A2;6;LEN(A2)-6))
5. in cel E2 enter: =IF(LEFT(A2;4)="    ";MID(A2;10;LEN(A2)-10);"")
6. finally in cel F2 enter the final formula: =IF(AND(B2=B3;C2="Father");"";IF(AND(B2<>B3;C2="Father");B2 & " " & D2;B2 & C2 & " " & D2 & " " & E2))

Now, if you select them all and drag the cells down to the end of the list, in column F you'll have the list of the clean codes: fathers with no 'sons' and sons: copy, paste special elsewhere and sort to remove the empty cells.

Can't post an image to show you the results: need at least 10 points of reputation to do so (!!!!)

Ciao!